# Facebook app on website platform PHP - Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-php-sdk

I've successfully developed Facebook canvas app [that runs inside iFrame] but now I want to move to the website platform.
So my app runs on my website and not inside an iFrame.
What are the changes need to be made ?

My app basically performs simple effects on the profile photo and then shows it to the user.

[I've tried changing the platform from Canvas to Website but it did not worked. It showed INVALID SIGNED REQUEST ERROR... ]

Here is a sample website which runs the app on their site, not inside an iFrame
http://in.testfun.net/

My canvas based app code

**config.php**

```
<?php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '**************',
'app_secret' => '1ef4838500bb8c401a18833dbcdfa27e',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',     ]);
$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
$permissions = ['public_profile','user_posts','user_location'];
$fbURL = 'https://apps.facebook.com/mytestapp';
$URL = 'https://localhost/apps/testApp/';
?>
```

**login-callback.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../fbsdk/autoload.php';
include 'config.php';

try {
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();    exit;
}
catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); exit;
}
if (isset($accessToken)) {
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;      header('Location: ' . $fbURL . $app);
exit;
}
else {  echo 'Oops unknown error!'; }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../fbsdk/autoload.php';
require_once '../fbsdk/FacebookRequest.php';
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
include 'config.php';

try {
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $accessToken;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();     exit;
}
if (isset($accessToken)) {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $longLivedAccessToken =     $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
 }
}
```

Comment: There is no signed_request for external website apps. So go change whatever part of _your code_ expects one, and outputs this error message.

Comment: @CBroe plz explain a bit more, better with an example. thanks

Comment: No one here knows your code. I can only guess that you used one of the login helpers of the PHP SDK - so you will need to switch out that part for the appropriate one (redirect helper or javascript helper; for both the documentation has examples.)

Comment: @CBroe I've added the code. Plz check and advice. & thnx

Comment: @CBroe I'm still waiting bro. Need help :(

Comment: As I said: You need to switch out the canvas helper for the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, You want to open facebook login page with OAuth.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: Also be aware about you have 2 different app on facebook. 
One of them just for developing env. and other one for production env. When You get you codes to production change the app_id and secret id for production mode configuration. And than set enable your app on facebook.